# Paragraph column in tabular working only in the first column

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a two-column `tabular` environment and I'd like for both of these columns to have the text aligned at its middle (both vertically and horizontally), along with increased row height:

But with the following input:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{1.8cm}|m{1cm}}
Problem & $\beta$ \\[0.2cm]
\hline
LCR-1 & 0.25 \\ [0.2cm]
\hline
LCR-10 & 0.05 \\ [0.2cm]
\hline
LCR-0.2 & 0.575 \\ [0.2cm]
\hline
Airplane & 0.05 \\ [0.2cm]
\hline
DR & 0.27 \\[0.2cm]
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Only the first column is as required. The text in the second column is still aligned at top left.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

{\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ C{1.8cm} | C{1cm} }
Problem & $\beta$ \\\hline
LCR-1 & 0.25      \\\hline
LCR-10 & 0.05     \\\hline
LCR-0.2 & 0.575   \\\hline
Airplane & 0.05   \\\hline
DR & 0.27
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Those `[0.2cm]` are responsible for the wrong vertical alignment. You could remove those and use `\arraystretch` instead, such as

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
```

If you do that within the `center` environment, the effect will be local, i.e. it will not affect the rest of the document. Here, used after `\begin{center}` its effect ends with the environment by `\end{center}`.

For horizontal centering you could use `>{\centering}m{1cm}` or even better, use Herberts suggestion requiring [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e).

Further suggestions:

- Use the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package for better spacing and improved customizable horizontal lines
- Avoid vertical lines, they make reading harder
- Align at decimal points instead of centering, for example using [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), [`rccol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rccol) or [`dcolumn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn)